# Are owned and borrowed strings guaranteed to hash to the same value?

Tags: hash, rust, hashmap

`String` and `str` both implement `Hash`, so we can hash either of them.  It appears that both owned and borrowed strings currently hash to the same value, so this assertion succeeds:

```
use std::hash::Hash;
use std::hash::Hasher;
use std::collections::hash_map::DefaultHasher;
pub fn main() {
    let hash1 = {
        let x: String = "abc".to_owned();
        let mut hasher = DefaultHasher::new();
        x.hash(&mut hasher);
        hasher.finish()
    };
    let hash2 = {
        let x: &str = "abc";
        let mut hasher = DefaultHasher::new();
        x.hash(&mut hasher);
        hasher.finish()
    };
    assert!(hash1 == hash2);
}
```

I'm writing code that leverages on this behaviour in the `raw_entry` API of `HashMap`.  Specifically, I'm using a HashMap where the keys are enums, but to reduce redundant allocations I want to do the lookup using "borrowed" versions of those enums.

In other words, in the following code I do need the guarantee that both assertions will succeed, regardless of the `Hasher` implementation being used.  It appears to me that this would depend on the guarantees provided by the `Hash` implementation of `String` and `str`.

```
use std::hash::Hash;
use std::hash::Hasher;
use std::collections::hash_map::DefaultHasher;
pub fn main() {
    {
        #[derive(Hash)]
        enum E1 {
            First(i32),
            Second(String),
        }
        #[derive(Hash)]
        enum E2<'a> {
            First(i32),
            Second(&'a str),
        }
        let hash1 = {
            let x: E1 = E1::First(100);
            let mut hasher = DefaultHasher::new();
            x.hash(&mut hasher);
            hasher.finish()
        };
        let hash2 = {
            let x: E2 = E2::First(100);
            let mut hasher = DefaultHasher::new();
            x.hash(&mut hasher);
            hasher.finish()
        };
        assert!(hash1 == hash2);
        let hash3 = {
            let x: E1 = E1::Second("abc".to_owned());
            let mut hasher = DefaultHasher::new();
            x.hash(&mut hasher);
            hasher.finish()
        };
        let hash4 = {
            let x: E2 = E2::Second("abc");
            let mut hasher = DefaultHasher::new();
            x.hash(&mut hasher);
            hasher.finish()
        };
        assert!(hash3 == hash4);
    }
}
```

Is it documented anywhere about such guarantees?  I would suppose that such guarantees must be provided (otherwise I see no way to properly implement the `contains_key()` method of `HashMap`, since the argument can be any borrowed form of the key), but I can't find this guarantee documented anywhere.

Comment: idk about guarantees, but https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/string.rs.html#1927-1932. I would be surprised if this ever changed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. This is guaranteed because `String` implements `Borrow<str>`.

Part of the contract for implementations of [`Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) is:

> Further, when providing implementations for additional traits, it needs to be considered whether they should behave identical to those of the underlying type as a consequence of acting as a representation of that underlying type. Generic code typically uses `Borrow<T>` when it relies on the identical behavior of these additional trait implementations. These traits will likely appear as additional trait bounds.
>
> In particular `Eq`, `Ord` and `Hash` must be equivalent for borrowed and owned values: `x.borrow() == y.borrow()` should give the same result as `x == y`.

In the standard library, the `Borrow` trait is used in [`HashMap::get`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get). `Borrow` makes it possible to pass a `&str` to `get` on a `HashMap<String, _>`. Naturally, in order for this to work, `&String` and `&str` must produce the same hash for the same string, hence the requirement on `Borrow`. The requirement is repeated in the documentation for `HashMap::get`:

> The key may be any borrowed form of the map's key type, but `Hash` and `Eq` on the borrowed form *must* match those for the key type.

---

Traits cannot define requirements like this in code, so it is possible for non-conforming implementations to exist as the compiler cannot enforce these requirements. However, such implementations would break `HashMap`.